Unable to do analysis on polygons from MSSQL
I have:

A polygon layer Zones with 9 polygons and
A point layer Users

Both are saved on Microsoft SQL Server. I want to do a spatial analysis for example "Count points in polygon".
The result always counts points for only the last polygon. If I export layer Zones from MSSQL to GeoPackage, analysis will work and it will count users in all polygons.
I tried reprojecting polygons, fixing geometries, and converting from multi to single, but it is still the same. When it is saved on MSSQL analysis doesn't work.
If it's saved as geopackage it works. It counts points in every polygon. I don't have to fix geometries. But when the same polygon layer is located on MS SQL Server, it counts points for only one (last) polygon.

Have you tried fix geometries and saving the results to a geopackage, then use this as input to count points in polygon?
